# Number of elements in a set of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $S$ be defined as $$S:= \left\{ M \in \mathbb{F}_3^{2 \times 2} : M \text{ is orthogonal} \right\}$$ where $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a field with $\mathbb{F}_3 = \{ 0, 1, 2\}$. How many elements does the set $S$ have?

---

I would like some advice on how to approach/solve this problem.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on finite-field matrices. Orthogonal means $MM^T=I$?

Comment: @Exodd yes, exactly

Comment: Since the numbers are very low, I suggest computing this by hand. For example you could solve $a^2+b^2 = 1$ so that you derive all possible rows of $M$, as a starting point, and since the only quadratic residues modulus 3 are 0,1...

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x,y)^T$ be a column of $M$. Then $x^2+y^2=1$ and at least one of $x$ or $y$ is nonzero. Suppose $x$ is nonzero. Then $x^2=1,y^2=0$ and $(x,y)=\pm(1,0)$.

It follows that every column of $M$ is, up to a sign, a member of the standard basis. Therefore $M=PD$ for some permutation matrix $P$ and some invertible diagonal matrix $D$. Hence there are $(2!)(2^2)=8$ choices in total, namely,
$$
\pmatrix{p&0\\ 0&q}\text{ and }\pmatrix{0&p\\ q&0}
$$
for any $p,q\in\{-1,1\}$.

---

**(Below is the old answer -- I misread the question and thought that $M$ was $3\times3$.)**

Let $(x,y,z)^T$ be a column of $M$. Then $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and at least one of $x,y$ or $z$ is nonzero. Suppose $x$ is nonzero. Since
$$
\text{every nonzero member of $\mathbb F_3$ squares to $1$},\tag{$\ast$}
$$
we have $x^2=1$ and $y^2+z^2=0$. Hence $y$ and $z$ are either both zero or both nonzero. The latter is impossible, or else $(y/z)^2=-1$, which is a contradiction to $(\ast)$. Therefore $y=z=0$ and $(x,y,z)=\pm(1,0,0)$.

It follows that every column of $M$ is, up to a sign, a member of the standard basis. Therefore $M=PD$ for some permutation matrix $P$ and some invertible diagonal matrix $D$ (this decomposition is unique, for, if $P_1D_1=P_2D_2$, then $P_2^TP_1=D_2D_1^{-1}$ and hence both sides are equal to $I$). Hence there are $(3!)(2^3)=48$ choices in total.

Comment: You solved a more difficult exercise :) 

The question deals with $2\times 2$-matrices

Comment: @Mathematician42 Oops, I thought $M$ was $3\times3$!

Comment: Also, I don't work with finite fields that often. The notion of an inner product seems nonsensical over finite fields. Are orthogonal matrices still "orthogonal" over finite fields in some sense?